# Looping over columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, loops, indexing

I am trying to divide every two columns by the last two columns in the data set. For example, I want to divide column[0] and column[2] by column[-2] and then store the result in column[0] and column[2], respectively.

Ideally, what I want is to obtain from this:

```
   fra1  ger1   fra2  ger2  fra pop  ger pop
0    12    14    525    52       14       14
```

something like this:

```
           fra1          ger1          fra2          ger2  
0    12/fra pop    14/ger pop   525/fra pop    52/ger pop
```

that is, I want to create a new Dataframe (that keeps the original column labels) by dividing values of each country by its population.
Doing this manually for every column would take too much time with the real dataset, and I cannot figure out how to run a loop.

Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I also found a solution:

```
divisor = df.iloc[:,-2:]
for index, column in enumerate(df):
    values = df[column]
    if index < 2:
        num1 = values
        df[column] = num1/divisor.iloc[:,index]
    if 1 < index < 3:
        num2 = values
        df[column] = num2/divisor.iloc[:,index-2]
```

Comment: You get a different result than you described in your question for `fra1` and `ger1`. Easy to see that `ger1` should be `1.0` in your example data.

Comment: yes, that is true. It's my mistake that in reporting sample data I removed observations and the code I posted does not account for that. I'll fix it immediately

Answer (score 1):

If you change your original organization you can do this much more easily, but from this point probably best to just use some logic to determine the prefixes and then perform the division for each subgroup and then join the results with `concat` in the end.

```
# Prefix is everything before `' pop'`
prefixes = [x.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] for x in df.columns if x.endswith('pop')]
#['fra', 'ger']    

l = []
for pref in prefixes:
    l.append(df[[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(pref) and not x.endswith('pop')]]
                .divide(df[f'{pref} pop'], axis=0))

res = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
#       fra1  fra2  ger1      ger2
#0  0.857143  37.5   1.0  3.714286
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However this method would not be implementable with the original dataset given the original labels.

Comment: @Luca I'm not sure I understand what you mean or why it would fail given the sample data you've provided

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not clear. I randomly created a dataset that featured the same characteristics of the original one, but reported variable names that I arbitrarily set. In the original dataset I have variable names that do not begin with countries' name.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the columns to fit your use case with [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) and `slicing`

Setting up the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
   fra1  ger1   fra2  ger2  fra pop  ger pop
0    12    14    525    52       14       14'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df
```

Out:

```
   fra1  ger1  fra2  ger2  fra pop  ger pop
0    12    14   525    52       14       14
```

The slices `[:4]` `[-2:]` and the multiplication factor `2` for the column names to devide by have to be adjusted for your real data

```
df[df.columns[:4]].div(df[df.columns[-2:].tolist()*2].values)
```

Out:

```
       fra1  ger1  fra2      ger2
0  0.857143   1.0  37.5  3.714286
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses pandas' multi-indexing and broadcasting.  Multi-indexing puts country and metric in two separate levels of the column labels.  Broadcasting lets you divide every German (or French) metric by the German (or French) population.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# add 2nd row to validate results below
t = '''
   fra1  ger1   fra2  ger2  fra pop  ger pop
0    12    14    525    52       14       14
1     2    3       4     5        6        7
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

# create hierarchical index (i.e., multi-index)
midx = [('france', 'm1'), ('germany', 'm2'),
        ('france', 'm2'), ('germany', 'm2'),
        ('france', 'pop'), ('germany', 'pop')]
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(midx, names=['country', 'metric'])
df.columns = midx

# create `metrics` data frame (excludes population)
metrics = df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['m1', 'm2'])]

# create population data frame (and remove one level of index)
pop = df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'pop')].droplevel(level='metric', axis=1)

result = metrics.div(pop, level='country')
print(result)

country    france   germany     france   germany
metric         m1        m2         m2        m2
0        0.857143  1.000000  37.500000  3.714286
1        0.333333  0.428571   0.666667  0.714286
```

More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html